# Filling window with a wxWebView

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I would like to fill an application window created with wxWidgets with a wxWebView. After reviewing the wxWebView sample, there the author created a wxFrame which then contained a wxBoxSizer and a wxWebView was added directly to that. However I would like my application to use a wxSingleChoiceDialog, so as far as I can tell, that means I need to include something like a wxPanel to use as the dialog's parent (the first argument to the constructor is the 'parent' of type wxWindow). So in my application I put a wxPanel in the wxFrame and then set the wxBoxSizer of the wxPanel to include the wxWebView. Unfortunately now the wxWebView no longer fits the full application window and I'm not sure why. Here is a simplified example of the application I'm trying to create.

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};


DECLARE_APP(MyApp)
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
#include "mainframe.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MainFrame *mainFrame = new MainFrame(wxT("Content Creator"));
    mainFrame->Show(true);

    return true;
}
```

mainframe.h

```
#ifndef MAINFRAME_H
#define MAINFRAME_H

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/webview.h>

class MainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    wxPanel *panel;
    wxBoxSizer *topsizer;
    wxMenuBar *menubar;
    wxMenu *file;
    wxWebView *webView;
    wxString editorURL;

    MainFrame(const wxString& title);
    void initMenu();
    void initEditor();
};
#endif
```

mainframe.cpp

```
#include "mainframe.h"

MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(800,600))
{
    panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);
    topsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    panel->SetSizer(topsizer);

    initMenu();
    initEditor();
}

void MainFrame::initMenu()
{
    menubar = new wxMenuBar;

    file = new wxMenu;
    //file->Append(wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"));
    menubar->Append(file, wxT("File"));

    SetMenuBar(menubar);
}

void MainFrame::initEditor()
{
    editorURL = "file:///C:/Users/kenwood/Desktop/MarkCreator2/ckeditor/samples/editor.html";
    webView = wxWebView::New(panel, wxID_ANY, editorURL);
    topsizer->Add(webView, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 0);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the application this creates: [Screenshot](http://s10.postimg.org/ronnxfsyx/screenshot.jpg)

Does anyone know how I might be able to make this wxWebView fill the application window (or at least why it isn't fitting the window because I'm clearly missing something here)? I realize I can create a wxWebView an specify a a size that would be equal to the window size, but then when the user resizes the screen webview is no longer the same size as the application window.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Also, I'm using wxWidgets version 2.9.4

EDIT 2:

It appears that calling initEditor() before initMenu() produces the desired result (but not the other way around). Would anyone know what the reason for this is? I would really like to call initMenu() first if that is possible.

Comment: Is it possible that this behavior is a bug in version 2.9.4 of wxWidgets? It seems wxWebView may be relatively new to wxWidgets. Would upgrading to the trunk build possibly fix this?

Comment: I tried using a wxPanel instead of a wxWebView and ended up with the same problem of the panel being displayed in the top left corner of the screen, so it seems my problems must be with my code. With this added info does anyone see where I might be making a mistake?

Comment: When creating your wxSingleChoiceDialog you should pass a pointer you your frame as the parent, not a wxPanel.

Comment: Well I tried this first but it turns out I had some other problems I overlooked and misinterpreted some of the errors I got. Thanks for setting me straight. I got it working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `webView` to the panels sizer. Your question actually doesn't have anything to do with `wxWebView` but just concerns the layout and I strongly recommend (re)reading the [corresponding section](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_sizer.html) of the manual.

Comment: Alright, I'll try the sizers overview (for the first time) and hopefully that'll improve a lot of my issues. Thanks for the advice again VZ.

Comment: I read the sizers overview and realized why you suggested it, fixed that problem (thx), but am still having the problem present in my full application. I updated the code provided. Q: Do you know why calling initMenu() before initEditor() (the reverse order works) would cause the webview to be displayed as the small box in the screenshot? Is this possibly a bug? I'm stumped and having trouble coming up with a google search the leads to someone with a similar problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, after a whole lot of banging my head on the desk I think I finally figured out why this wont work. I believe it's because wxWebView doesn't have a proportion parameter and so you must set its size explicitly. I misunderstood carelessly assumed that wxDefaultSize meant fill the screen since, when I was testing, I used wxDefaultSize for a wxPanel that was a direct child of the wxFrame and it filled the window. As far as I can tell though, the default behavior for any first child of the wxFrame is to fill the window.

Comment: I'm assuming this means I need to listen for the resize event and then manually resize all the windows I care about? Is there not a more automated method for handling this? Sorry, this is one of my first wxWidgets applications and I'm still struggling to fit it all together.

Comment: Finally got all my mistakes worked out. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having similar problems, one of the main problems with my code is that I was creating the 'panel' before creating the menubar. By calling initMenu() as the first function call in the constructor I was able to get the webview to display in the full application window --advice provided by the illustrious 'doublemax' of wxWidgets forums. Thanks for everyone's help.